# Apply the result of a jQuery function back to the selected element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I apply the result of a jQuery function directly to the element that I'm selecting? Take this snippet, for example:

```
$('#textinput').val($.trim($('#textinput').val()));
```

This snippet is selecting the value of a text input, trimming the whitespace, and replacing the result back to the input's value.

While this works, my gut tells me there's a more efficient way. Is there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, there is: use contextual `this` provided in the callback:

```
$('#textinput').val(function() {
    return $.trim(this.value);
});
```

While it has a few more characters, the method is way more maintainable because you don't have to remember to update the selector twice. Also, another advantage is that the callback is iteratively applied to all nodes selected in the jQuery object, i.e. this will also work, if you want to trim the values of *all* input elements on the page:

```
$('input').val(function() {
    return $.trim(this.value);
});
```

Comment: Yes. Definitely cleaner. Thanks. I still feel like there should be a shorthand version of this pattern like in @Rory-McCrossan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57311396/81767) below… but no support in IE is a dealbreaker (aren't we past the _works everywhere except IE_ thing yet?!).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a more efficient way; you can provide a function to `val()` which accepts the current value as an argument. You can then amend it and return the new value, like this:

```
$('#textinput').val(function(i, value) {
  return value.trim();
});
```

This can be made more succinct by using an arrow function (although note that it won't work in IE):

```
$('#textinput').val((i, value) => value.trim());
```

Comment: Since this solution doesn't involve `this` (context-independent), I believe it could also be written as a one-liner : `$('#textinput').val( (i, val) => val.trim() )`, am I right?

Comment: Yes indeed, so long as you don't need IE support. I updated the answer to include it.

Comment: I like the shorthand version, but the IE thing is a dealbreaker.

Comment: Unfortunately that's the way with IE :( The first example will work in any browser, though